# github pipeline unable to deploy bw6 application

Tags: github-actions, pom.xml, cicd, tibco

Trying to deploy an BW6 application using github action pipeline but getting the following error

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:2.9.2:bwinstall (default-bwinstall) on project ee.vndrCisco.eventMsg.entEvent.application: Failed to deploy BW Application: Error reading entity from input stream. Unrecognized field "servlet" (class com.tibco.bw.maven.plugin.admin.dto.Error), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "code", "message"])
Error:   at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.tibco.bw.maven.plugin.admin.dto.Error["servlet"])
Error:  -> [Help 1]
```

in pom.xml maven plugin is 2.9.2 only, below is my pom.xml of parent folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tibco.bw</groupId>
  <artifactId>application-name.application.parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
   
    <module>../application-name.entEvent</module>
    <module>../application-name.application</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
        <deployToAdmin>${pushToAdmin}</deployToAdmin>
        <agentHost>${Agenthost}</agentHost>
        <agentPort>${Agentport}</agentPort>
        <domain>${Domain}</domain>
        <appSpace>${Appspace}</appSpace>
        <appNode>${Appnode}</appNode>
        <httpPort>${Agentport}</httpPort>
        <redeploy>true</redeploy>
        <profile>${Profile}</profile>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>   
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.tibco.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>bw6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    
</project>
```

in all the other pom.xml also containing maven plugin version 2.9.2 and the github runner also installed with 2.9.2